# Page Layout for Knowledge

Tags: knowledge

Is there a way to remove the Sample Title and Sample URL Name from the page layout in Salesforce Knowledge? Answer is my custom field that I have added. When I click the wrench next to Sample Title and Sample URL Name it does not allow me to untoggle it as Required. Thanks[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce Universally required fields cannot be removed from the Page Layout and cannot be marked as read only.

Here, Title and URL Name are always required field in Page Layout.

Other example could be `status` field in `Case` object.